# Change the overlay image live in wikitude?

Tags: wikitude

Is it possible to change the overlay image after a certain time or period with using the WikiTude ImageTarget? Even live without restarting the camera view?

Comment: @sjOrske have you found any solution? I am looking for same in android.

Comment: @JayShah I did not, but I think you have to do this with a Ajax request in the javascript. I currently not working with wikitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `AR.ImageDrawable` (`var overlay = new AR.ImageDrawable(img, 1,{}`); ) you can change the image resource by calling `overlay.imageResource = newImg;` Put this code into a function and call it with a timer or anything else.

Hope I've been able to help you.